# I am unable to set a background image property for a div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a fairly trivial CSS issue that I can't solve. I want to set my landing page's background image as a file saved in my directory called "basketball.jpg" but when I set the background-image property for the sign up div it shows a white screen but setting the property with a body selector works.

CSS

```
.form {
  background-image: url('../basketball.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

JSX

```
  <form className="signup-form">
        <div className="form">
          <div className="signup">
            <h3 className="header">Create your free Basketball Guru account</h3>
              <div className="form-group center-block">
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input type="name" className="form-control login" placeholder="Username" />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="password"></label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control password" placeholder="Password" />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              <p className="form-snippet">Already signed up? Log in</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Your selector is wrong, it's `form` to the form using it's tag name or `.signup-form` to select the form with it's class

Comment: I tried that as well to no avail. When setting width or other properties for example I see a change on the screen for .signup-form but setting background-image doesn't affect it. Setting background image as a property for body like above gets the desired result but I don't want to set it as the image for every page on my site.

Comment: the changes i suggested worked  form and they're the write way to do it, if you still can't see an image it only means the path to the image is wrong

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the tree structure of your files

Comment: That's weird. It's the same directory but I only changed the selector from .signup-form to body.

Comment: Are you using React? It works for me in a fiddle when I use `class` instead of  `className` in the html. Or if you're using Bootstrap or similar, it might be overriding your styles with the same class name

Comment: Yeah, I was using bootstrap and React but I removed  bootstrap link because I came to the same conclusion. I'll try with class instead of classname. I might create another project, I didn't have much code anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `basketball.jpg` in your public folder, and then access it in your css like this:

```
.signup-form {
   background-image: url("/basketball.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
}
```

It's due to the way React bundles the styling files, it all ends up in the `public` folder and so your path didn't work.